# Jquery adding a few variable to hover event

Tags: jquery, variables, hover

i creating some a-tags and store this in different variable. Now, i want add a hover event to this stored variable.

something like that

```
var btnPrev = $(document.createElement('a'));
btnPrev.css({
    'display':'block',
            ...
});
btnPrev.text('<');
btnPrev.addClass('issueBtnPrev');
var btnNext = $(document.createElement('a'));
btnNext.css({
    'display':'block',
            ...
});
btnNext.text('>');
btnNext.addClass('issueBtnNext');
```

now here is the hover event

```
(btnNext,btnPrev).hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200,'0.3');
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200,'.2');
});
```

but only the btnPrev have a hover effect is there a way to attach more than one vaiable to a hover effect.

i know i can use
    $('.issueBtnNext, .issueBtnPrev').hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add another jQuery object (or an element, HTML fragment, etc.) to the current set:

```
btnNext.add(btnPrev).hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200,'0.3');
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200,'.2');
});
```

From the jQuery docs on `add`:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method.

Your current attempt only works for `btnPrev` because you are using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which evaluates both of its operands (which in your case does nothing) and returns the last, which in your case is `btnPrev`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) an element to the matched set:

```
$(btnNext).add(btnPrev).hover(...);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/qSYXk/